# NTL Library: How to assign a big integer to ZZ_p

Tags: c++, ntl

In NTL library I know that we can define a big integer value as:

```
ZZ p;
p=to_ZZ("1111111111111111111111111111111333333333333333");
ZZ_p::init(p);
ZZ_p b(12);
```

**My question is**: What if I want to assign a big integer to b rather than 12 ?

e.g.

```
ZZ_p b("1111111111111111111111111111111333333333333334");
```

So it should modulo `p` and assign `1` to `b`.

I need it for `fFindRoots(vec_ZZ_p& x, const ZZ_pX& ff)`, so would be able to insert big integers to a vector as coefficients (of a polynomial)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: I tried the code you posted and the line `ZZ_p b(12);` did not work for me.
I had to use

```
ZZ_p b;
b = 12;
```

If you want to assign a big integer you can do this by

```
ZZ_p b;
b = to_ZZ_p(conv<ZZ>("1111111111111111111111111111111333333333333334"));
```

or

```
char bigInteger[47] = "1111111111111111111111111111111333333333333334";
ZZ_p b;
b = to_ZZ_p(conv<ZZ>(bigInteger));
```

`cout << b << endl;` will now print `1`.

Comment: Do yo know how to assign a replace "111....33334" with a variable. as I have an array of big integers and I want to convert them to ZZ_p. I tried: string s="111....33334" ; b = to_ZZ_p(conv<ZZ>(s)); but it's not working.

Comment: @user5111525 what type do your "big integers" have?

Comment: of type "mpz_t"  GMP big integers.

Comment: @user5111525 I'm not sure how to convert this to `ZZ` type. My guess is, that you have to convert to a cstring first. I added an example.

Comment: Thank you.  I did as follows:  1- convert big integer to string: string s="111111.....2"; 2- char*cc=new char [s.length()]; 3-strcpy(cc,s.c_str());  4- ZZ_p b=to_ZZ_p (conv<ZZ>(cc));